# Integral question - $\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\ln(x)}}$

Tags: integration

This is the integral : $$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\ln(x)}}$$

This is what I did so far:

$$U=\frac1{\sqrt{\ln(x)}} \implies U'=-\frac{1}{2}{\frac{\ln(x)}{x}}$$
$$V'=\frac{1}{x} \implies V=\ln(x)$$

$$\int UV' = UV - \int(VU')$$
Am I doing the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\ln(x)=t$. We then have $x=e^t$ and hence
$$I = \int \dfrac{dx}{x \sqrt{\ln(x)}} = \int \dfrac{e^t dt}{e^t \sqrt{t}} = \int \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}$$
I trust you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $$(f^p)'=pf'\times f^{p-1}$$

so let $f(x)=\log x$ then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ then
$$\int \dfrac{dx}{x \sqrt{\ln(x)}}=\int\dfrac{f'(x)dx}{ \sqrt{f(x)}}=2\int \frac{1}{2}f'(x)(f(x))^{-1/2}dx=2(f(x))^{1/2}+C=2\sqrt{\log x}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

In general:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x} f(\ln{x}) = \int du \, f(u)$$